Searching for an image tagging and OCR APK
I have tons of Screenshots, Pictures of people and docs.
I want to tag them so that I can search it sort of how files by Google does by recognising text from screenshots.
So i was trying to find if there is an app for Android.
it should have following requirements
requirements

it should detect and recognise photos by face
it should do it on device and should not upload on any server
it should embed it's face recognition database into image itself preferably xmp tagging
it should read text from screenshots and make them searchable preferably by other tagging APKs also

Preferences

it would be very nice if that app can recognize nature scenes, objects, animals, birds, etc but face recognition is my priority


I'm afraid this is where the hi-tech fails to deliver as expected yet, although the technology is coming and may be available very soon. There are some interesting startups, such as imagga.com, which strive to approach the automatic recognition technology and make it public, however doing all the same locally from your device without communicating a remote server is hardly an option for business they try to run (especially if you want to recognize photos by face which your device has no prior knowledge of). Manual tagging for pics that you have collected is the most likely way for you to advance right now, and for that you may consult the exiftool community forum. FastPhotoTagger is an app that I run on my Android tablet to tag and do the searches.

I have used Google gallery in past which they have discontinued which recognise same person and keep them in an album. Files by Google's smart search can find any image which has any text in it just by searching even if it is handwriting. What amaze is that they do this offline. For files app, I think  it do this by cross matching my full searched word "captain" for example by searching its database and finding any word with cap* and then checking if words it  was not sure about while indexing is *tain. Sorry for confusing. I should learn English
